# Typo3 plugins load order

Tags: typo3

Is there any way of controlling the load order of plugins? The load order has recently been changed on my site (I have no clue why) and I need to restore it. I was trying different things but with no luck.

My TypoScript is as follows:

```
#plugin pi2 is used for render the page content. It is placed on page in visual editor
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 = USER
page.10.userFunc = tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page

#plugin pi4 - this should run after pi2
lib.banner < plugin.tx_marvelino_pi4
```

I was trying to change the order of defined variables, edit templavoila mapping and get rid of templavoila main page call and run pi2 dirrectly and pass to page.10.CONTENT but it did not work.

Comment: Would be nice to get some more details about `I was trying different things` and `no luck`. For instance: What exactly have you tried and what was the result?

Answer (score 3):

The order is defined in `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList']` and `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXT']['extList_FE']` in the `typo3conf/localconf.php` or the corresponding array elements in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` if your TYPO3 is v6.0+

When you install new extensions in the backend, the most recent ones just get added at the end. When you uninstall extensions, those are just taken out of the list.

**UPDATE:**

You can not only use `page.10` to assign objects to the rendering queue, but any other number as well. The natural order of the numbers is also the rendering order in the frontend then.

```
page.10 < plugin.tx_whatever_pi2
page.20 < plugin.tx_marvelino_pi4
```

Comment: Sorry but I meant "plugins" - not "extensions"!

Comment: Ok, I agree. Your idea is brilliant! However, there is one small problem. Please note that 'lib.banner' is templavoila reference to a page element and 'page' is just PAGE object. How can I queue them? I mean I would like to run page.10 < plugin.tx_whatever_pi2 at first and after that lib.banner < plugin.tx_marvelino_pi4. Is it possible when they are different objects?

Comment: I would have to know your complete typoscript setup and the cause for your extensions to be in a specific order (which I consider a bad software design). Without this (quite complex) information, I would just answer your last question with `No`. BTW: personally, I really dislike templavoila for the fact that it makes the TYPO3 site much more complex from a developer point of view. I prefer the typoscript/extbase/fluid way of doing things in TYPO3.